# How to boot windows 8 tablet into safe mode

Tags: boot, windows-8, tablet

I have an HP ElitePad 1000 G2 (no keyboard) that has a seriously damaged boot configuration and cannot run any fix/diagnostics neither windows advanced recovery mode.
Error:

> `Boot Configuration Data File is Missing`

How can I boot into safemode to use at least command prompt and try to fix things?

Every time it tries to boot it gives errors about Boot Configuration missing or Corrupt and hangs, or it goes up to User-Login screen and then hangs with similar error about boot conf.

Comment: USB keyboard maybe?

Comment: You won’t be able to boot to Safe Mode.  Your BCD is corrupt

Comment: @gronostaj The tablet does not provide USB port, so usb keyboard is not an option, unfortunately..